# Custom Windows Control Library in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, custom-controls

I've created a customized Text Box using Windows Forms Control Library, and which have options for `Numeric Text Box`, `Alpa Numeric Text Box`, `Decimal` etc...

I've overridden the `PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)` Method to do this.

Here is my sample snippet for `Numeric Text Box`

```
    public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)
    {
        int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        if (msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            Keys keys = (Keys)msg.WParam.ToInt32();
            bool bNumbers = false;
            switch (eType)
            {

                case enTextBoxTypes.Numeric:

                    bNumbers = ((keys >= Keys.D0 && keys <= Keys.D9) || (keys >= Keys.NumPad0 && keys <= Keys.NumPad9)) && ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(bNumbers.ToString());
                    if ((keys == Keys.OemMinus || keys == Keys.Subtract) && bAllowMinusSign && ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift)
                    {
                        bIsOEMMinus = (keys == Keys.OemMinus) | (keys == Keys.Subtract);
                        if ((this.Text.Length != this.SelectedText.Length || !bAllowMinusSign) && this.SelectionStart != 0)
                            bIsOEMMinus = false;
                    }

                    break;
            } 
            bool bDel = keys == Keys.Delete;
            bool bBack = keys == Keys.Back;
            bool arrows = (keys == Keys.Up) | (keys == Keys.Down) | (keys == Keys.Left) | (keys == Keys.Right);
            bool Enter = (keys == Keys.Enter);
            bool ESC = (keys == Keys.Escape);
            bool TAB = (keys == Keys.Tab);
            bool Home = (keys == Keys.Home);
            bool End = (keys == Keys.End);

            if (bNumbers  bBack | bDel | arrows | Home | End | bIsOEMMinus)
                return false;
            else if(TAB)
                return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
            else
                return true;                
        }
        else
            return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
    }
```

Now I need to implement the `unit` in the Textbox
for this I've added a new enumeration in the `TextBox type` i.e. `Distance`.
So if I entered a decimal number, and after that if I pressed the `k` key then the text box value should be appended with `Km`

for example if the text box's text is `100` and then I pressed `k` then the text box's text should be `100Km` .

And also I need to provide the unit change functionality to the `Up Down` keys.

So if i press the `down` key in the text box with the above value , then the text box value should be `100000m`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a masked Textbox if this is your question. Because I see you already have the KeyDown in use and I think you know how to handle.
[Walkthrough: Working with the MaskedTextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx)

```
Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000"
MaskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = GetType(System.DateTime)
```

[Mask edit sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just inherit the textbox control and alter the OnTextChanged and onkeydown events. Look at [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c#/) link, he uses both the events. (Don't look at the name though)

If you don't think this will help you for whatever reason, please explain me what holds you.